# how to set crontab every 10 minutes delete content of log file on linux

Tags: linux, cron

I wanna delete content of log file (/var/log/httpd/access_log) every 10 minutes, Please show me how to do that with crontab in linux
Help me please
Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Get to know logrotate instead. In case you really want to do this, put `*/10 * * * * root rm -f /var/log/httpd/access_log` into `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: after cron run this action,then client access web server, why dont access_log write log??? help me!? thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open root's crontab for editing in default editor:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then add this line:

```
*/10   *    *    *    *    echo '' > /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

Comment: after cron run this action,then client access web server, why dont access_log write log??? help me!? thanks a lot

Comment: My proposed script just clears access_log file. In this case can not be any flaws. What is your `ls -alF /var/log/httpd/access_log` output?

Comment: output: -rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 1 Dec  3 16:32 /var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: If you have `BufferedLogs On` in your config, then Apache will buffer log entries in memory before writing to disk. That's why you may see new log entries after some time pass. Try `BufferedLogs Off` setting.

Comment: somtimes when I make any change in this log file. then it's not write log anymore except my computer is restarted

Comment: please show me how to make BufferedLogs Off setting. I just studied how to use linux. thanks a lot

Comment: Find your httpd config: `sudo find / -name 'httpd.conf'` and change `BufferedLogs` parameter there.